# Escape button for iPad Pro with Microsoft Universal Foldable keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, terminal, bluetooth

I need to use escape for VI on my iPad Pro.
I have the Microsoft Foldable keyboard, 
I have already tried `Ctrl` + `[` and it doesn’t work.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: the official documentations states that the ESC key under IOS behaves like "Browser Back key function". Did you try using it with the `Fn` key?

Comment: Yes I tried using the `Fn` key. Also, the `Fn` and the `Cmd` key are the same in this keyboard.

Comment: Bummer... the app you're using doesn't have an emulated function pad for the most used function keys?

Comment: I am unable to use escape key in safari as well. I have vim plugin added in Sharelatex, even there I am unable to use it. Does that mean that safari also doesn’t have that emulated.

Comment: just a crazy idea... but what if when you pair it to the ipad, you choose to use it as a Windows keyboard? you will probably lose the IOS functions but it sounds to me like you want to use it more for data entry than for screen navigation anyway...

Comment: I tried that. The keyboard stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>.</kbd>  seems like this command used to be a way for halting/canceling operations in both MacOS or Windows.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/9vsxmo/til_cmd_in_ios_invokes_the_esc_key/